# Video chat mobile web application without WebRTC?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, webrtc

I am looking to develop a mobile friendly video chat application in the form of a web app (not an iPhone/Android app). It will largely be used by desktop and mobile iOS users. I understand that iOS only supports WebRTC for the Safari browser and not Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Is their an alternative technology to WebRTC for creating a video chat mobile web application that has support for the Chrome browser on iOS?

Or is it the case that if I want users to use the video chat web application from their iPhones that they will need to use Safari?

Comment: The [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458) looks like it may be addressed in iOS14.3.  However, the underlying problem is access to media devices in WebKit, so I suspect that any video chat would be impossible in Chrome on iOS (prior to 14.3 if it is fixed in that version) since you can't access media devices rather than it being an issue with WebRTC itself.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is what I was looking for. I'll just support safari for now and if this gets pushed looks like Chrome will be supported soon.